# What is the term for words that were once polite and became impolite?

Tags: american-english, meaning

Sort of the opposite of a euphemism but not exactly -- I am thinking how the word "lady" when used to address an adult, female stranger seems to have a negative connotation as in "Listen, lady..."

Answer (score 7, accepted):

*Pejoration* is when a once-neutral word picks up negative connotations over time. A word that is marked by its negative connotations can be called a *dysphemism*, as in the opposite of a euphemism.

But I'm not sure "lady" is either of those. You could swap in pretty much any form of address in that context ("listen, *miss*", "listen, *ma'am*", "pal", "dude") and it would have the same connotations. In other words, the negative connotation in your example isn't any property of the word; it's a property of the way it's being used, and the prosody and such surrounding it.

Comment: I can guarantee you that if you call a stranger "Lady" you will get a negative or perhaps amused reaction. "Miss" or "ma'am" would work much better.

Comment: As Draconis mentions pejoration is the term you’re looking for, but the example you give is not related to your question.

Comment: @user15493: what is the term for being bad at providing illustrative examples? I may suffer from this disorder, lady.